# :nth-child(n):before is doesn't working?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have question: does `:nth-child(n):before` working?

So, I using SASS.
Why following code is not working?

```
@for $i from 1 through 4
  .block:nth-child(#{$i}):before
      background: url(../../img/block-img-#{$i}.jpg)
      background-size: cover
```

It's compiling to:

```
.content .cnt1 .block:nth-child(1):before {
  background: url(../../img/block-img-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.content .cnt1 .block:nth-child(2):before {
  background: url(../../img/block-img-2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.content .cnt1 .block:nth-child(3):before {
  background: url(../../img/block-img-3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.content .cnt1 .block:nth-child(4):before {
  background: url(../../img/block-img-4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

All dirs to images is true. But it's not working :(
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also give an example of the respective HTML?

Comment: you also need to add `content:''` to the before-rule, and I guess you'll need to set a width and height for the element, otherwise the background might be applied to a 0px x 0px element.

Comment: Why are you setting background-size: cover in every rule? That seems like a quick way to completely bloat your CSS.

Comment: @Sirko https://github.com/RamoFX/RamoFX2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do pseudo-elements require a 'content' property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067918/why-do-pseudo-elements-require-a-content-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By itself, a `::before` pseudo element is not visible. You will also need to give it a `display` property, and some content. Otherwise, it won't show.

Now you haven't provided the HTML, but if I can presume that it's just a bunch of nested divs, the required extra CSS looks like this.

```css
.content .cnt1 .block::before {
  display:block; content:'';
  height:200px;                /* a height, any height */
}
```

Or for a more complete example: (never mind the background images)

```css
.content .cnt1 .block::before {
  display:block; content:'';
  height:200px;                /* a height, any height */
}
.content .cnt1 .block:nth-child(1)::before {
  background: url(http://images.clipartpanda.com/number-clipart-niXxEn7iB.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.content .cnt1 .block:nth-child(2)::before {
  background: url(http://images.clipartpanda.com/clipart-numbers-9czE7pRpi.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.content .cnt1 .block:nth-child(3)::before {
  background: url(http://images.clipartpanda.com/creation-clip-art-RTAE8d8TL.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.content .cnt1 .block:nth-child(4)::before {
  background: url(http://images.clipartpanda.com/number-clip-art-RcA6Axgji.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="cnt1">
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

By the way, the notation for `:before` with one colon is deprecated; the preferred way is `::before`.

Or, if you want to use `:before` for compatibility with older browsers, then be warned that you can't use `background-size` either.
That is, the only reason to use `:before` is if you want to be compatible with IE8. `:before` works in IE, `::before` doesn't.
But since IE8 doesn't support `background-size` or `nth-child()`, you won't get this particular example to work in IE8 anyway, so there's no need to bother.

Comment: Oh yeah! I did than sh.. a lot of time and I didn't know where is the problem.. Thank you so much!

Comment: I doubt if using a single colon precludes using `background-size`. Also, why would I need to add an explicit `display` property?

Comment: @torazaburo: Mr Lister is saying that [the only browser in the world that supports only the single-colon syntax doesn't support background-size anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28527928), so using the single-colon syntax for compatibility is pointless if you're going to rely on background-size. The display: block declaration is required - unless said declaration already exists elsewhere or some other declaration exists that causes them to be blockified - because pseudo-elements don't have a default display value, so they take the initial value, inline, and the height property will not apply.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the clarification. But I thought all browsers supported the single-colon syntax.

Comment: @torazaburo: All browsers support the single-colon syntax so that stylesheets designed for IE8 and older will continue to work. But the only browser that *doesn't* support the double-colon syntax for ::before and ::after is IE8 (older versions don't support these two pseudos at all). The single-colon syntax is deprecated (and is invalid on ::selection and all other pseudo-elts defined in various CSS3 specs), and authors are strongly encouraged to use double colons for the sake of consistency, and other than IE8 compat there is no good reason to use single colons for any pseudo-elements today.