# What is the difference between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

What is the difference between `div::after {}` and `div:after {}` ? When do we have to use `::` over `:`?

> Double colon and single-colon notation is to distinguish between
> pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements.

What is the actual meaning of the above statement?

Comment: Further disambiguation: [What is the difference between a pseudo-class and a pseudo-element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css) | [Should I use single colons (:) or double colons (::) for before, after, first-letter and first-line pseudo-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684797/should-i-use-single-colons-or-double-colons-for-before-after-first-le)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements

**Pseudo-class :**

> A CSS pseudo-class is a keyword, preceded by a colon (:), added to the end of selectors to specify you want to style the selected elements, and ***only when they are in certain state***. For example, you might want to style an element only when it is being hovered over by the mouse pointer, or a checkbox when it is disabled or checked, or an element that is the first child of its parent in the DOM tree.

Examples:

- :active
- :checked
- :nth-child()
- :first
- :hover

**Pseudo-elements ::**

> Pseudo-elements are very much like pseudo-classes, but they have differences. They are keywords, this time preceded by two colons (::), that can be added to the end of selectors ***to select a certain part of an element***.

Examples:

- ::after
- ::before
- ::first-letter
- ::first-line
- ::selection
- ::backdrop

As stated by @stephanmg:

> In practice ::before is used as :before and ::after is used as :after
>   because of browser compatibility. Both are pseudo-elements, but may
>   look like pseudo classes. This might be confusing if you read CSS
>   code.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to note that in practice ::before is used as :before and ::after is used as :after because of browser compatibility. Both are pseudo-elements, but may look like pseudo classes. This might be confusing if you read CSS code.

Answer (score 10):

**Pseudo-classes :**
it is applied automatically by the browser
depending on the position of the element or its interactive state.

*For Example :*

`E:hover` Matches elements of type E when the cursor is
hovering over it.

**Pseudo-elements :**
It is applies styles to content
based on its position in the HTML hierarchy.

*For Example :*

`E::first-letter` This applies a style to the first letter of the first line inside a block-level
element E.

**So ,**

The CSS3 Selectors specification prefixes pseudo-elements with two colons instead of one.
So, :first–letter becomes ::first-letter and :first-line becomes ::first-line.
IE 8 and earlier don’t understand the double-colon prefix, so you need use
the single-colon versions to avoid styles breaking in older browsers.

Comment: If `::first-letter` is a pseudo-**element** because the browser "*applies styles to content based on its position in the HTML hierarchy*" then why are `:first-child`, `:nth-child(...)` etc. not pseudo-elements? They also apply styles based on the position of an element in the html, the same argument as for `::first-letter`.

Comment: @Ehsan may you reply to Steeven's question?