# Images do not show in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox

Images do not show in Firefox ... Safari, Chrome, Opera OK.

BUT, this works everywhere?

```
<img class="headerImage centerImage" src="images/Broken_Heart.gif" alt="crying">
```

```css
.headerImage {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.brokenHeart {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  content: url("../images/Broken_Heart.gif");
}

.weddingRings {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  content: url("../images/Wedding_Rings.gif");
}

.centerBlock {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerImage centerBlock">
  <img class="brokenHeart" alt="">
  <img class="weddingRings" alt="">
</div>
```

Weird, it's just in Firefox ...

Appreciate some genius here, because I'm falling very short.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content url does not display image on firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser)

Comment: What's the thinking behind doing it that way instead of `<img src="/images/Broken_Heart.gif">`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24185344/2397327. Excerpt: "url is not a valid 'content' type and even tho Chrome and Safari are being the good guys and show it nicely."

Comment: Well, url can be used with content, but content cannot be used unless doing `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: For most reliable consistency throughout various browsers, consider using the `background-image` property instead, or applying the `content` property to `:before` or `:after` *pseudo-elements*.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Pseudo elements should use a double colon, not a single. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after I cannot duplicate this problem.

Comment: I followed L.K.'s advice <img src="/images/Broken_Heart.gif"> and it worked perfectly. Once again, the simple way may be the best way. Thanks again, LK.

Comment: @Rob As a rule yes, but both can be used. The double colon is to *distinguish* between *pseudo-classes* and *pseudo-elements*. According to MDN on *pseudo-elements*: "As a rule, double colons (::) should be used instead of a single colon (:). This distinguishes pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements. However, since this distinction was not present in older versions of the W3C spec, most browsers support both syntaxes for the original pseudo-elements." ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements For better legacy browser support it may be better just to stick with single.

Comment: @Rob See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181729/should-i-use-single-or-double-colon-notation-for-pseudo-elements and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867664/double-colon-vs-single-colon-at-css-syntax (I'm sure you already know this, although for other readers who may be unsure as to the reasons why)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError As a rule is the rule you should follow. Unless one needs to support IE8 and older, use the double colon. That's the standard.

Comment: @Rob I'll continue to use single colons for legacy browser support regardless, that is just my preference, although I would advise others to follow their own discretion, and if unsure, then stick to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Content is making this error, so adding :after should do the trick for firefox

```
.brokenHeart:after {
display: inline-block;

  width:   100%;

  content:  url("../images/Broken_Heart.gif");
}

.weddingRings:after {
  display: none;

   width:   100%;

   content: url("../images/Wedding_Rings.gif");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition of content property as given in MDN web docs.

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after
> pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

In your code you are trying to apply the content property directly on class selector which is present on the HTML element. Firefox tends to ignore this attribute altogether.

```
.brokenHeart {
    display: inline-block;
    width:   100%;
    content:  url("../images/Broken_Heart.gif");
}
```

To make it work in Mozilla you need to modify your CSS like this.

```
.brokenHeart {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    content:  url("../images/Broken_Heart.gif");
}

.brokenHeart:after{
    content:  url("../images/Broken_Heart.gif");
}
```

Keep the content property on element (for Chrome) and add a pseudo-element `:after` (for Mozilla).

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old thread. I came here looking for a solution too. The answer is straightforward:

Instead of using this format, "C:\Users..." etc, use this style, "file:///C:\Users..."

The reason for this format is that Firefox blocks paths to local files that start with "C" for security reasons. The new format won't affect Chrome or Edge.

Happy coding.