# 'filter' attribute pixelates my font?

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve a color of red on a button that only seems possible to get by using `filter: brightness(x)`. The problem I have with this is, most importantly, that utilizing this style slightly but unmistakably pixelates the font of the button, but also it brightens text color along with the background.

I have tried adding the text after the styling, but it is all the same. This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnhsqv0j/61/) demonstrates the problems described.

How can I counter or avoid this effect? Or achieve a brighter color without using brightness filter?

Comment: Why would brighten it, instead of just styling it that way using `background-color` and `color`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you may notice that the brightness filter has no effect on your background color (remove the text and see that there is no effect) simply because your color is `red = rgb(255,0,0)` and this filter apply a linear transformation which is a simple multiplication of the RGB values having the max value 255. In you case you have a value bigger than 100% so the color will remain the same!

```css
button {
  color: white;
  display:block;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  border:none;
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
}


button:hover{
  filter: brightness(180%);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

By the way an idea is to use a pseudo-element to create the background on where you apply your filter and avoid changing the text:

```css
button {
  color: white;
  display:block;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:relative;
  background:none;
  border:none;
}
button:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:rgb(180,20,20);
  z-index:-1;
}

button:hover::before {
  filter: brightness(180%);
}
```

```html
<button>The quick brown fox (hover me)</button>
```

Comment: In the first example when I hover the button, it actually changes color I believe.. it is very, very slight. but it does. Also, if you increase the brightness value it will be very evident that it changes at least.

Comment: @user2651804 no it doesn't change :) try to pick the color value and see ;) the only change is applied to font and border and thus you have this illusion of color change

Comment: In the second example you write `button:before` is it a typo that there aren't 2 colons?

Comment: @user2651804 no it's not a type ;) both works, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867664/double-colon-vs-single-colon-at-css-syntax

Comment: I'm unable to do that in the dev console.. but I did in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qnhsqv0j/88/

I can both SEE the change, and Colorpicker tool confirmed a change from #ff001f to #ff0038

Comment: @user2651804 you used red and red is `#ff0000` and not `#ff001f`

Comment: I can understand why a colorpicker tool might be inaccurate, but not why it would label identical colors differently? Either way there is no denying a color change if you increase the brightness value. But I guess that still just transforms the color code, and that is not what I had expected.

Comment: and if you used `#ff001f` you may see that the ff didn't change the 00 didn't change and only 1f was change to 38

Comment: @user2651804 well i based my logic on simple math calculation .. the brithness apply a transformation as follow `C' = p * C` where p is the value specified in the filter and in this case it will be 1.8 [180%] ... and the value is maximized to 255 ... so if you mutiply 0 by p it will be equal to 0 and if you multiply 255 by 1.8 you will get a big value and thus we keep 255

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can just pick a color you like in a hexadecimal format. You can find plenty of websites that offer pallets to pick from. Then you can just delete the filter like so [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnhsqv0j/60/)

```
button {
  color: white;
  display:block;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  background: #ff0022;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting.. so brightening colors just result in different plain color codes? https://jsfiddle.net/qnhsqv0j/77/
In this fiddle I have 3 buttons. Starting from the bottom 1) example of achieving what I want for another color. 2) exactly what I want to achieve for red, but without brightness. 3) failed attempt to replicate button 2.