# Why I cant do multiple placeholder selector in LESS

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

Just want to add css **prefix** like
`::-moz-placeholder` and `::-webkit-input-placeholder`

**So I will do multiple selector in LESS :**

```
::-moz-placeholder, ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:red;
}
```

It doesn't work ? Why?

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/pfg3Q/

---

**But Its work when i do normally like :**

```
::-moz-placeholder {
 color:red;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:red;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pfg3Q/1/

---

What I did wrong ? Wonder this is about LESS or not?

**Ref:** Prefix came from http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone found the related issue already on SO:
[Should I use single or double colon notation for pseudo-element css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181729/should-i-use-single-or-double-colon-notation-for-pseudo-element-css#answer-10181948)

Basically, if any selector in your comma separated list is not recognized by your browser, it skips the whole rule and goes on to the next.

```
// Chrome
::-moz-placeholder // <-- I don't know this one, skipping!

// Firefox
::-moz-placeholder, ::webkit-input-placeholder // <-- I don't know this one, skipping!
```

But if you seperate them in single statements, it won't skip the one it knows.

So, as a rule of thumb: *if you have vendor-prefixes, always split them up into seperate rules*.

Comment: This is ! . Back to basic.... thanks so much :D

Comment: How is that other question related to this one? That one talks about single/double colon notation for pseudo-elements, while this one talks about prefixes.

Comment: @BoltClock The question itself is indeed not related, but the accepted answer explains why the comma-separation can have some nasty side effects. I've updated my link to jump to the answer immediately.