# CSS :after content (HTML entity) mobile compatibility

Tags: android, html, css, html-entities

I'm running into an issue with an HTML entity inside of :after content. It's working on most browsers and devices, but there seems to be a problem with certain android devices.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
.side-arrow::after{
    position:relative;
    content:"\025B8";
}
.down-arrow::after{
    position:relative;
    content:"\025BE";
}
```

Is this an issue with the HTML entity or with the CSS content? For some devices it doesn't show up at all and others it shows a blank box as if it's an image.

If there's a way to fix this without needing an image fallback, that would be ideal since there are a number of different colors and sizes needed.

**EDIT**

In the case of no support, what would be an alternative to adding the symbol to just those devices?

Comment: What it has to do with android?

Comment: Have you tried `:after` rather than `::after`? For some reason I think the latter has less support (not sure though).

Comment: @Apurva It has to to with android because it isn't happening on any apple devices, and perhaps it's an android bug.

Comment: @JoshCrozier It was my understanding that two colons was better than one?

Comment: [**CanIUse - Pseudo-Elements**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

Comment: @testing123 According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181729/should-i-use-single-or-double-colon-notation-for-pseudo-element-css) IE7/IE8 don't support the double colon notation.. so it's possible the same applies for older Andoids. Not sure though. According to Paulie_D's link above, it shouldn't matter, though. So I guess that's not the issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D Perfect, thank you. I've revised my question to ask for an alternative for browsers without the needed support.