# Write ::before or :before for the css selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Both are working but what is the best practice?

W3Schools says :

> Notice the double colon notation - ::first-line versus :first-line
>
> The double colon replaced the single-colon notation for
>   pseudo-elements in CSS3. This was an attempt from W3C to distinguish
>   between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements.
>
> The single-colon syntax was used for both pseudo-classes and
>   pseudo-elements in CSS2 and CSS1.
>
> For backward compatibility, the single-colon syntax is acceptable for
>   CSS2 and CSS1 pseudo-elements.

I went for "::" but I don't have backward compatibility then...

Comment: There is no real answer except that using a single colon `:` is backwards compatible with browsers such as IE8. In theory the single colon syntax support could be dropped in future browsers, but that is unlikely and a matter of opinion. There doesn't seem to be a reason not to use it if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: Already discussed in [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10181729/2930477) with a bunch of opinions.

Comment: That quote is from W3Schools, **not** W3C. I've edited the question. W3C is the World Wide Web Consortium which holds the various HTML and CSS specifications. W3Schools is an unrelated (and often lowly-regarded) website which attempts to convert the various specifications into simple English.